# How to run bash command with arguments at scheduled time

Tags: bash, scripts, schedule

I have a bash file which runs a process on a series of newly downloaded files, every day, the total run time for all the processing is several hours.

I want to run a particular bash command 24 hours after a process has been run on a particular file.

I had tried to use `at` for this, however I don't think you can use at to run a bash command i.e.:

```
at now +24 hours gsutil rm gs://$google_cloud_storage_location/$processed_file
```

And I also can't get it to run a bash script with arguments.

```
at now +24 hours -f example_script.bash $google_cloud_storage_location/$processed_file
```

What is the correct way to go about scheduling these tasks? Do I just need a completely different tool or am I missing a way with `at`?

Example bash script:

```
for file in list_of_files; do
    #do some processing
    ....
    #then delete the file
    at now +24 hours gsutil rm gs://file
done
```

Comment: How about `at now +24 hours /usr/local/bin/doit`, and begin `/usr/local/bin/doit` with `#!/bin/bash`, followed by what you want?

Comment: @waltinator So I have a loop in by bash file which is running this code and if I don't provide it with the variable then, I'm not sure how I get it to delete the correct file. How I do provide the variable in that example?

Comment: I *think* you need to pass the command to `at` via stdin - either something like `echo "command <args>" | at now +24 hours`, or by using a heredoc `at now +24 hours << EOD; command <args>; EOD`

Comment: @steeldriver aaah spot on - pushing the commands through echo worked like charm. if you want post a full answer so I can mark as correct or I can write up myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your variables to be substituted at the time of setting the job up, you can accomplish running a simple bash command with `at` by simply piping the command to `at` with echo. For your first example, the syntax would be

```
echo "gsutil rm gs://$google_cloud_storage_location/$processed_file" | at now +24 hours
```

For the second example, the syntax could be

```
echo "/path/to/example_script.bash $google_cloud_storage_location/$processed_file" | at now +24 hours
```

If the variable substitution needs to be performed at the time of the job, it is a bit trickier. You will need to create a script that runs when the job is to be done, substituting at the proper time. This can be done using a command exclusively (e.g. from a script) by doing

```
echo -e '#!/bin/bash' > /path/to/script
```

Then

```
echo '<your command here>' >> /path/to/script
```

Then the syntax for the `at` command is

```
at now +24 hours -f /path/to/script
```

Of course, the `+24 hours` part should be adjusted to the proper duration.

Answer (score 1):

Since `at` reads commands from stdin or from a file:

```
for file in list_of_files; do
    #do some processing
    ....
    #then delete the file
    at now +24 hours <<EOF
gsutil rm gs://"$file"
EOF
done
```

Using heredocs to provide the commands would work, since variables are expanded in heredocs unless the heredoc marker (`EOF`, here) is quoted.